# python, beautiful soup, xml parsing

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

How can I get values of latitude and longitude from the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<location source="FoundByWifi">
<coordinates latitude="49.7926292" longitude="24.0538406" 
nlatitude="49.7935180" nlongitude="24.0552174" />
</location>
```

I tried to use `get_text` but it doesn't work in this way(

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
lat = soup.find('coordinates','latitude').get_text(strip=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'latitude' is an attribute within the 'coordinates' tag. Once you found the coordinates, the soup object stores all the attributes in a dict-like key-value store.

So, in your case, after finding the coordinates tag, check the 'latitude' key as so:

```
lat = soup.find('coordinates')['latitude']
```

You can even strip the resultant of any extraneous whitespace at the beginning or end:

```
lat = soup.find('coordinates')['latitude'].strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Check online demo](https://repl.it/H9ob/1)

```
html_doc = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<location source="FoundByWifi">
<coordinates latitude="49.7926292" longitude="24.0538406" 
nlatitude="49.7935180" nlongitude="24.0552174" />
</location>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
lat = soup.find_all('coordinates')

for i in lat:
  print(i.attrs['latitude'])
  print(i.attrs['longitude'])
```